# node command to set env variable works on linux and mac but not on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

After I git clone a project I can't run `npm run build` on Windows, although it's working on Mac and Linux :

```
"build": "API=https://dev-api.myexample.com/v1.0 babel-node build.js",
```

I got this error :

> 'API' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Did  you try to run the commend from a new console ?

Comment: @HristoStaykov new console? what's that for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `cross-env` (add it first to your dependencies with `npm i cross-env` see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

```
"build": "cross-env API=https://dev-api.myexample.com/v1.0 babel-node build.js",
```